# Protect a resource video file

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I tried to protect my resources using this way:
http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/

All would be good except of my video files. The thing is that when I'm decrypting them I get `NSData` objects which I can't load in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Regarding to the remaining resources. They look useless and contain of non-reading data.

Is there a way to protect my video-files which can be received from the project with applications like `iFunBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that method is going to accomplish is preventing folks from directly copying the resources and using them.  It's not difficult to capture the key and perform the decryption.

I do not think you can feed raw data into the standard player control.  However, you can use lower level core video API, which is much beyond a simple SO question/answer.

Since the method you are using just discourages the convenient pirate, one option for you is to decrypt the movie file into an actual movie file on the file system.  This means that the decrypted version of the movie will reside on the file system, which significantly reduces your minimal security.

However, you can possibly remove it right after the movie controller takes over.  Since you probably don't want the file sticking around, you can unlink (i.e., remove) it after the movie controller has taken over.

As an Obj-C programmer, you are familiar with reference counted objects.  Files in the file system are reference counted (albeit somewhat differently).

The actual file remains on the file system until there are no references to it.  The name in the file system is not much more than a link and reference count to the control block in the file system.

When a file is opened, the open file descriptor constitutes another reference to the actual file.  Thus, as long as its file descriptor remains open, the file will remain on disk.

However, since the file system link (i.e., the file path) is gone, it is a little more difficult to discover for mere mortals.

As long as the movie player controller keeps the file open, the contents remain in the file system, and it should work.  If, for some reason, the movie controller closes the file, or wants to do stuff based on the file name alone instead of the file descriptor, you may have problems.

Try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to (re)create file from NSData,  then play it. Anyway, if someone makes a memory dump of app running the chances to catch decrypted file is fairly good.